# How to solve for the torque when there is more than one lever arm?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

I have encountered this problem in my Giancoli physics textbook and I would like to seek your kind guidance regarding a simple point of confusion of mine.

In this problem, we are asked to find the components of the force exerted by the hinge on the door, and we are given the dimensions of that door. Finding the vertical component was fine, no problems encountered. But the problem lies within finding the horizontal components.

In the solutions manual, it used different lever arms for each force involved, is this acceptable? If so, can you make me understand why so.

Also, I tried to draw a schematic representation of a possible explanation, can you please tell me if it is logical or not

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lever arm for the counter clockwise torque about the bottom hinge is the perpendicular distance between the line of action of the gravitational force and the bottom hinge. The clockwise torque about the bottom hinge is due to the horizontal reaction at the top hinge where the lever arm is the distance between the hinges. Thus the lever arms are different. Your schematic looks correct regarding the lever arms.

But while their lever arms are correct, all their solutions are incorrect because the problem is what is called "statically indeterminate". Statically indeterminate means the equations of equilibrium are insufficient to solve for the reactions. The underlying physical reason is there are redundant reactions.

Take for example the vertical reactions at the hinges. Their equation

$$\sum F_{y}=F_{Ay}+F_{By}-mg=0$$

is correct. But then they incorrectly conclude that

$$F_{Ay}=F_{By}=\frac{1}{2}mg$$

The first equation tells us that any combination of $F_{Ay}+F_{By}$ that equals $mg$ is possible, up to and including that $F_{Ay}=0$ or $F_{By}=0$. The vertical reactions of the hinges are redundant. You can remove either one and the door could still be in vertical equilibrium, as long as the single remaining hinge, as well as the door and door jam where the hinges are screwed into, are capable of supporting the entire load.

Next consider rotational equilibrium. In their free body diagram of the door they fail to include the moment reactions possible at the hinges. I am using the term "moment" instead of "torque" because that's the term used in statics to describe a torque (at least it was when I took statics over 50 years ago).

A frictionless hinge offers no moment reaction to the movement of the door perpendicular to the plane of the door, i.e., no moment reaction to the swinging of the door. But the hinges, or more properly the hinges plus the door jam where the hinges are screwed into, do provide a moment reaction to the weight of the door since the hinges cannot rotate in the plane of the door. In effect, the hinges are what are called "cantilever supports". A cantilever support provides vertical, horizontal and moment reactions.

So the sum of the torques (moments) about hinge B equation should be

$$mg\frac{w}{2}-F_{Ax}(h-2d)-M_{B}=0$$

where $M_{B}$ is the clock wise moment reaction of hinge B.

Similarly, the sum of the moments about hinge A are

$$mg\frac{w}{2}-F_{Bx}(h-2d)-M_{A}=0$$

where $M_{B}$ is the clock wise moment reaction of hinge B.

Finally, we have

$$F_{Ax}=F_{Bx}$$

Note that we now have three equations and four unknowns ($F_{Ax}$, $F_{Bx}$, $M_A$, and $M_B$). Once again we have redundant reactions. In this case the redundant reactions are the moment reactions of the hinges. They are redundant because, once again, we can eliminate either hinge and the door could still be in rotational equilibrium, as long as the remaining hinge (and the door itself) is strong enough to provide the necessary moment reaction. Which is why one would never have a door with a single hinge to provide all of the support.

When a problem is statically indeterminate, one has to include additional equations relating to the deformations of the structure and the material properties. That is the subject of mechanics of deformable solids.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you so much @bobd

Comment: So is my answer acceptable?

Comment: So far yes, why would you think otherwise ? @bobd.

Comment: Never mind. On re-examining the problem, although the lever arms are correct per my answer, I find the problem to be conceptually incorrect. It’s statically indeterminate

Comment: Can you please elaborate further on how it is conceptually incorrect, please pardon me, I’m a beginner in physics.

Comment: I will update my answer to explain

Comment: @DoePual See my update. Sorry if it's a bit long.

Comment: I can’t thank you enough for everything you’ve written, I am honestly grateful. Thank you for clarifying this and widening my perspectives and scopes in this regard. This really means a lot for me, you know, like coming back again after a day trying to explain it in a better way. Thanks Sir!

Comment: @DoePual You're welcome. You could show your gratitude by formally accepting my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a statics problem (with no rotation) any point can be chosen a reference point for calculating torques. You normally choose a point which eliminates one of more torques. If your first choice eliminates one of the unknowns, you can do another calculation with a different reference point.